# Using Google Analytics account for development environment

Tags: google-analytics

We currently have a google analytics account for our production environment.  However we need to have a separate google analytics account for a dev environment that is not pushing any analytics data to the production one.  Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may simply create a different "property" under the same Google analytics account. A different tracking code will be available, for you to use in the development environment.

cf. "[Set up a property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508?hl=en)" documentation.